# Can I use letter ä in urls?

Tags: urls

I have the following beginning on my tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
```

Now I need to put an URL to the document that contains the letter ä. I tried to do this

```
\url{http://www.address.fi/kälä-example}.
\url{http://www.address.fi/k\"al\"a-example}.
```

but this won't work in my system. Can I see those addresses properly somehow?

Comment: you could use `hyperref`'s `\href` command, which allows you to separate the URL from the label. I would probably encode the URL part using http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: But encoding gives the address %25C3\%25A4 and this looks ugly in by document. I tried `\usepackage{hyperref}` and `\url{ä}` but it gave me `\protect\unhbox\voidb@x\bgroup\U@D1ex{\setbox\z@\hbox{\char127}\dimen@
-.45ex\advance\dimen@\ht\z@\fontdimen5\font\dimen@}\accent127\fontdimen5font\U@Da\egroup.
`

Comment: @studying Uwe is right. The letter “ä” is not valid in URIs. See [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986): “[…] such use is not defined by this specification. Percent-encoded octets (Section 2.1) may be used within a URI to represent characters outside the range of the US-ASCII coded character set”. I agree, the encoded URL is not pretty. But an ugly valid URL is better than a pretty invalid one.

Comment: @marco: iirc, there's an rfc which supersedes that one.

Comment: @morbusg Usually the RFCs contain an “Updated by …” link in that case, which RFC 3986 does not. Which RFC supersedes RFC 3986, can you post the number or a link?

Comment: @studying Do not use `\url{}`, but `\href{url}{label}`. this way you can mask the ugly looking %23 stuff

Comment: Correction: RFCs contain an “Obsoleted by …” link in that case, not “Updated by …”.